# vtkActor::SetPointSize not setting the point size beyond some value

Tags: vtk

In my application, i am rendering some point data.  Using vtkActor::GetPointSize function to set the point size in pixels i.e., screen units.  Point size beyond 10 pixels does not have any effect.  Is it a limitation?  Same this is observed in the following sample code.  Point size above 50 pixels has no effect.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointSource> pointSource = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointSource>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputConnection(pointSource->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);
actor->GetProperty()->SetPointSize(200);

// A renderer and render window
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

// An interactor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

// Add the actors to the scene
renderer->AddActor(actor);
renderWindow->Render();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken this simply boils down to OpenGL restrictions on point sizes.